# Express.js and MySQL model + validation

Tags: mysql, node.js, validation, express, model

I am developing application using Node.js and Express framework. I found many examples of modeling data using MongoDB, but my project requires SQL database.

Could someone make simple explanation, what is the best way to make models based on MySQL?

Also I am wondering how to provide later validation of those models. Maybe I should define validation attributes inside each of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no best way to make models based on MySQL. You could implement your own way to handle models, but there are many ORM modules available for Node.js, I'd suggest using one of those.

I use [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) as ORM to define models and interact with the database in several Express applications. Another ORM for Node that I've run into is [Bookshelf.js](http://bookshelfjs.org/), but there are many others. Wich one to use depends on your preferences and necessities.

**EDIT: Example of usage**

I suggest the following structure when using Sequelize models: a directory in your project named models with a file for each model and an index.js file to load the Sequelize environment. If you use the [Sequelize CLI](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html#the-cli), it also has several methods that follow this structure.

**index.js**

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
let sqize = new Sequelize({
  host     : "1.2.3.4",
  port     : 1234,
  database : "testDb",
  username : "pino",
  password : "th1S1s@c0mpL3xP4sSw0rD",
  dialect: 'mysql',
});

fs.readdirSync(__dirname).filter(function(file) {
  return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.js");
}).forEach(function(file) {
  let model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
  db[model.name] = model;
});

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.op        = Sequelize.Op;

module.exports = {
  sqize: sqize,
  Sequelize: Sequelize,
  op: Sequelize.Op
};
```

**users.js**

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  let users = sequelize.define('users', {
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    firstname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    secondname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(4),
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'users_type',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    salt: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'users'
  });

  users.associate = function (models) {
    users.belongsTo(models.user_types, {
      foreignKey: "type",
      as: "userType"
    });
    users.hasMany(models.user_logs, {
      foreignKey: "user_id",
      as: "userLogs"
    });
  };

  return users;
};
```

For more parameters and details, you can check the Sequelize doc, which is very simple and full of examples and details.

Also, I've used some ECMAScript 6, so change or transpile this code if your version of Node.js does not support them.

Comment: Thank you for your respond, about Sequelize. I already have entire db schema designed, is this module allowed me to use ready(existing) db?

Comment: Yes, you can use on already existing DB. Just be aware that when running Sequelize.sync() method, the structure of the DB is synched with the models and could generate structure alteration. I'm using Sequelize on an existing DB not generated through Sequelize (it's used by several others app without Sequelize) and I avoid to execute the sync method. In this case, some errors could be generated if the model is outdated. But that's a problem if your models are the one used to create the DB structure. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, I got it, last thing I would like to request you, because I've never worked with Sequelize, could you attach just simple code example of your project that connect with schema and make model of one of the table. Thank you in advance.