# Why the Associations do not work in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I need to know why my code isn't working. I'm trying to make a cart table which is going to have a foreign key userId and productId.
To achieve that, in my product model and user I do what I follow:

```
User.hasMany(Car,{
    primaryKey:'userId'
})

module.exports=User;

  Product.hasMany(Car,{
      primaryKey:'productId'
  })

module.exports = Product;
```

in Car model I have:

```
 const {Model, DataTypes}=require('sequelize');
    const sequelize=require('../config/database');
    const Product=require('./Product');
    const User=require('./User');
    
    class Car extends Model{}
    
    Car.init({
        id:{
            primaryKey:true,
            allowNull:false,
            type:DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue:DataTypes.UUIDV1
        }
    },{
       sequelize,
       modelName: 'car'
    });
    
    module.exports=Car;
```

I'm getting this mistake:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFoF1.png)

I need help.

Answer (score 1):

You should register all models in Sequelize and only after that register their associations. Also don't import models to each other model files. Define `associate` function in each model to register associations. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618)

Comment: Exactly. If you need another answer very similar to Anatoly's one, there's mine too [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48946275/express-js-and-mysql-model-validation/48947228#48947228)